# Slash in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-config

I am trying to set email credentials in web.config and the username has a slash in it:

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp from="test@mydomain.com">
        <network defaultCredentials="true" enableSsl="true" host="test.clientdomain.com" password="password" port="25" userName="domain\admin" />
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Now whenever I see a "\" in a string, I tend to escape it with a "\". But I am not sure if this is required in case of **userName** in web.config.

Do I need to escape the "\"? If not then why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No in `web.config` you don't need to escape `"\"` because for xml everything that located between quotes is a value of attribute. And backslash do not have any special meaning for xml.

There is list of characters that you need to escape:

```
"   &quot;
&   &amp;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
'   &apos;
```

Thanks to ps2goat for correcting me.

Comment: And ampersands (&), greater than (>) and less than (<) signs.  Those would be "&amp;", "&gt;", and "&lt;", respectively (without quotes, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Web.config does not accept this. Be careful !

see; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuration-based-activation-in-iis-and-was

Any ‘\’ (backslashes) in a URI sent to IIS/WAS are automatically converted to a ‘/’ (forward slash). If a relative address is added that contains a ‘\’ and you send IIS a URI that uses the relative address, the backslash is converted to a forward slash and IIS cannot match it to the relative address. IIS sends out trace information that indicates that there are no matches found.